# How to find recursive parent in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Employee JSON object

```js
var sampleObject = [
    {
      employeeId: 1,
      employeeName: 'E1',
      managerId: null
    }, {
      employeeId: 2,
      employeeName: 'E2',
      managerId: 1
    }, {
      employeeId: 3,
      employeeName: 'E3',
      managerId: 1
    }, {
      employeeId: 4,
      employeeName: 'E4',
      managerId: 3
    }
]
```

In the typescript, how to find the recursive manager id to the top most until manager is null.

Suppose, here I want to find the top most Manager of the E4.

How to achieve that. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear can you refine it. `what do you mean by "top most manager of e4"`

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: "*JSON object*" - so, a javascript object?   JSON = string

Comment: do you want to return the most parent (highest manager) or do you want the hierarchical architecture?

Comment: This JSON has no parents, only siblings. And what do you mean by “the top”?

Answer (score 3):

```
const sampleObject = [
    {
      employeeId: 1,
      employeeName: 'E1',
      managerId: null
    }, {
      employeeId: 2,
      employeeName: 'E2',
      managerId: 1
    }, {
      employeeId: 3,
      employeeName: 'E3',
      managerId: 1
    }, {
      employeeId: 4,
      employeeName: 'E4',
      managerId: 3
    }
]

function getRootManager(id: number, fined: number[] = []): number {
  const employee = sampleObject.find(e => e.employeeId === id);

  // Prevent 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'
  if (fined.indexOf(employee.managerId) !== -1) {
    return employee.employeeId;
  }

  if (employee.managerId !== null) {
    return getRootManager(employee.managerId, [...fined, employee.managerId])
  } else {
    return employee.employeeId;
  }
}

console.log(getRootManager(4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take an iterative approach with an object for the name/id relations and id/manager relations.

```js
function getTop(name) {
    var top,
        id = staff.name[name];

    while (top = staff.manager[id]) id = top;

    return id;
}

var array = [{ employeeId: 1, employeeName: 'E1', managerId: null }, { employeeId: 2, employeeName: 'E2', managerId: 1 }, { employeeId: 3, employeeName: 'E3', managerId: 1 }, { employeeId: 4, employeeName: 'E4', managerId: 3 }],
    staff = array.reduce((r, { employeeId, employeeName, managerId }) => {
        r.name[employeeName] = employeeId;
        r.manager[employeeId] = managerId;
        return r;
    }, { manager: {}, name: {} });
    
console.log(getTop('E4'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd ask you to add your attempt but I quite like doing recursive functions as it doesn't come up in my day job very often. I haven't added in the Typescript attributes, because I feel like it should be relatively simple to add a parameter type and return type once you make a type for `Employee`.

```
function findHighest(employee) {
    const managerId = employee.managerId;

    if(managerId) {
        const managerObject = sampleObject.find(sample => sample.employeeId === managerId);
        return findHighest(managerObject);
    }

    return employee;
}
```

This function will take an employee object, find its managerId, if it has a managerId, it finds the corresponding employee object for that manager, and passes that back into itself. Otherwise if no managerId is found, it will return the employee object (which will be the top level manager object as opposed to the id because the managerId will always be null).

Recursion can be a bit confusing at first, but I re-iterate that it would be better to see your attempt before asking on here. (you'd learn more!)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sampleObject = [{
    'employeeId': 1,
    employeeName: 'E1',
    managerId: null
  },
  {
    employeeId: 2,
    employeeName: 'E2',
    managerId: 1
  },
  {
    employeeId: 3,
    employeeName: 'E3',
    managerId: 1
  },
  {
    employeeId: 4,
    employeeName: 'E4',
    managerId: 3
  }
];


let findHierarchy = (emp) => {
  let manager = null;

  if (emp.managerId) {
    var managerObj = sampleObject.find((o) => o.employeeId === emp.managerId);
    manager = findHierarchy(managerObj);
  }

  emp.manager = manager;

  return emp;
}

let e = {
  employeeId: 4,
  employeeName: 'E4',
  managerId: 3
};

let output = findHierarchy(e);

console.log(output);
```